# Mixpanel iOS - How to MPTweakBind a UIButton text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, mixpanel

Using the MixPanel iOS SDK I want to use the `MPTweakBind` on a UIButton but am finding it hard to apply it on a UIButton because its title properties are read-only.

I've tried the following without success;

This complains of NSString from incompatible void

```
UIButton *submitBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 30, 30)];
MPTweakBind(submitBtn, titleLabel.text, @"Button Text");
```

This complains of NSString from incompatible void

```
MPTweakBind(submitBtn.titleLabel, text, @"Button Text");
```

I'm sadly stuck at this point, how do I apply the MPTweakBind onto a UIButton?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create you own subclass from UIButton with some property for example `NSString *textForTweakBind`. In setter you should write:

> [self setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

//.h file

```
//  MyButton.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textForTweakBind;

@end
```

//implentation file

```
@implementation MyButton

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)setTextForTweakBind:(NSString *)textForTweakBind {
    [self setTitle:textForTweakBind forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

Than you can try to use MPTweakBind with this button:

```
MyButton *submitBtn = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 30, 30)];
MPTweakBind(submitBtn, textForTweakBind, @"Button Text", @"Button Text 2");
```

I hope it will helps)

Comment: I'm wondering if I could do the same using KYO?  The app we intend to do this in would be very big changes.  Custom labels, custom buttons.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know how can you use KVO in this case. I think KVO doesn't help. You should do this only for this case with UIButton title, cause titleLabel is readonly.

Comment: Okay.  Well I was thinking I could do this: `[self.actionButton setTitle:[self.actionButton valueForKeyPath:@"titleLabel.text"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Looks like your right, MPTweakBind seems to have no context of the valueForKeyPath.  Thats a shame!

Comment: I think subclassing may help.

Comment: Your solution is accepted.  It will do for us for now whilst I will investigate it further